# Is it possible to use two dictionaries at the same time in swype?

Tags: keyboard, swype, dictionary

I type in two languages regularly - depends on who I communicate with, in perhaps 60:40 or 70:30 ratio. Sometimes I even use words from both languages in the same text. Both languages are supported by Swype. But I can only select one of them at one time, so when I need to type in the other language I have to change the settings, which is quite inconvenient. Can I merge two dictionaries or activate both of them at the same time?

Comment: you can long-press on the letter Q to quickly change language on Swype

Comment: wow you're right.. you can post that as an answer imo.

Comment: It's still inconvenient, multiple dictionaries active at the same time would be a neat feature.

Comment: agreed. Still this is better than having to change the Settings.

Comment: I also recommend suggesting this to the Swype people.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

you can long-press on the letter Q to quickly change language on Swype

Answer (score 1):

You could also try to just add the words you use most of the time, even it is from a different language.

That is what I do. When I'm using one language, and I need a word that is available in the other language, I just type it and add it to my personal dictionary. Over time I will have two dictionaries who will probably both have the words I use the most.

Answer (score 0):

Swype from swype symbol to q to quickly change between two most recently used languages.

[Easy language change on the keyboard](http://forum.swype.com/showthread.php?1253-Easy-language-change-on-the-Keyboard)

Answer (score 0):

Another Stackoverflow question about using multiple keyboards on Android: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20197421/adding-a-second-dictionary-to-the-spell-check-in-android-4-3/44033793#44033793

**Here is how for example to have a *French keyboard* with *French dictionary* + *French keyboard* with *English dictionary***

Go to `Android settings > Language & Input > Gboard` (Google default keyboard).

Then in `Languages`, you can tick all the keyboards you want. In my case, `French (France)` and `English (UK)`.

This will give you the usual AZERTY French keyboard and the usual QWERTY English keyboard.

If you want the English dictionary with a French AZERTY keyboard, you can go to `Preferences > Personalised input styles` and create a new keyboard `Language: English (UK) Layout: AZERTY`, then in the `Languages` menu, you will have a new keyboard in the list, `English (UK) (AZERTY)`. Tick it.

You now have 3 keyboards in your list: `French (France)`, `English (UK)` and `English (UK) (AZERTY)`.

While using the keyboard, you can then switch from one keyboard to another either with the special button or by holding the `Space` bar. The `Space` bar also shows the current language being used.

**Using multiple dictionaries at the same time:** In `Text correction`, there is an option called "multilingual suggestions", this will use several dictionaries *at the same time*, recognising as valid all words from the selected languages. If active, the `Space` bar will show something like FR-EN, to indicate that several languages are active at the same time. I personally don't like it.